# How to take input in 2d-array using Golang?

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array, backend

**Golang**
as u can see in this code(.go) am trying to input 2d arrays and storing even integers in even array and for odd in odd array. But we can see in its output as i mentioned below after code in comments it skips indexes during input? and even array can't get the even values. What am doing wrong?

```
 package main
    import (
    "fmt"
    )
    func main() {
    numbers := [4][4]int{}
    even := [4]int{}
    odd := [4]int{}
    row := 4
    col := 4

    fmt.Println("Enter data in your 2-D Array")
    for row = 0; row < 4; row++ {
        for col = 0; col < 4; col++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &numbers[row][col])
            if numbers[row][col]%2 == 0 {
                even[row] = numbers[row][col]
            } else {
                odd[row] = numbers[row][col]
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Printing 2D Arrays", numbers)
    fmt.Println("Print Even Array", even)
    fmt.Println("Print Odd Array", odd)

    }
    //My output is as follow
    //Printing 2D Arrays [[1 0 2 0] [3 0 4 0] [5 0 6 0] [7 0 8 0]]
    //Print Even Array [0 0 0 0]
    //Print Odd Array [1 3 5 7]
```

Comment: I think you are doing this wrong. Correct me if it is not. Your `numbers` has 16 elements and `even` and `odd` have 4 elements for each.  so you need 2D array to match `event` and `odd` elements?

Answer (score 1):

You have 16 elements in your input and you try to store those elements in length 4 `even` array and length 4 `odd` array. then it is obvious to skip 8 elements there. You can use append to even and odd arrays.

Note :- when you declare 2D array, `[rows][columns]int{}`. Be aware when iterating through this, otherwise it can be a Out of bound panic.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    numbers := [4][4]int{}
    var even []int
    var odd []int
    //row := 2
    //col := 4

    fmt.Println("Enter data in your 2-D Array")
    for row := 0; row < 4; row++ {
        for col := 0; col < 4; col++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &numbers[row][col])
            if numbers[row][col]%2 == 0 {
                even = append(even, numbers[row][col])
            } else {
                odd = append(odd, numbers[row][col])
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Printing 2D Arrays", numbers)
    fmt.Println("Print Even Array", even)
    fmt.Println("Print Odd Array", odd)

    //Printing 2D Arrays [[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8] [9 10 11 12] [13 14 15 16]]
    //Print Even Array [2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16]
    //Print Odd Array [1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15]

}
```

Comment: Sir thnks for ur kind reply. Num array must store 16 elements but it is just storing 8 elemets and skiping 8 elements problem lies here in this statement **fmt.Scanf("%d", &numbers[row][col])**. See the output (Printing 2D Arrays [[1 0 2 0] [3 0 4 0] [5 0 6 0] [7 0 8 0]])  i only enter 8 elemets others are by default zeroo.

Comment: Can you run this code i have posted above and see the results? I have edited it with my outputs